# AJAX - POST ' data:' - Uncaught error- unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to resolve this exception?

```
AJAX - POST at 'data:' - Uncaught error- unexpected identifier
```

code

```
$.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('test/testData'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {var TTDNo1: $("txtTTDNo1").val();//---Here on browser shows an error ' Uncaught error- unexpected identifier'
                        var TTDNo2 : $("txtTTDNo2").val(); var TTDNo3 : $("txtTTDNo3").val();
                        var TTDNo4 : $("txtTTDNo4").val();                    
                        var CaliExpDate1 = $("txtCaliExpDate1").val();// which operator to use? '=' or ':'
                        var CaliExpDate2 = $("txtCaliExpDate2").val();
                        var CaliExpDate3 = $("txtCaliExpDate3").val();
                        var CaliExpDate4 = $("txtCaliExpDate4").val();
                },
                success: function(){
                    alert("Data added successfully");
                }
                failure: function(){
                    alert("Please try again...");
                }
    });
```

Comment: There should not be the `var`

Comment: End each property with `,` not `;` - `data: {
  TTDNo1: $("txtTTDNo1").val(), //---Here on browser shows an error ' Uncaught error- unexpected identifier'
  TTDNo2: $("txtTTDNo2").val(),
  var TTDNo3: $("txtTTDNo3").val(),
    TTDNo4: $("txtTTDNo4").val(),
    CaliExpDate1 = $("txtCaliExpDate1").val(), // which operator to use? '=' or ':'
    CaliExpDate2 = $("txtCaliExpDate2").val(),
    CaliExpDate3 = $("txtCaliExpDate3").val(),
    CaliExpDate4 = $("txtCaliExpDate4").val(),
},
`

Comment: "no need" sounds optional, it's actually invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

woooowww, that to bad, correct your code as below

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('test/testData'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        TTDNo1: $("txtTTDNo1").val(),
        TTDNo2: $("txtTTDNo2").val(),
        TTDNo3: $("txtTTDNo3").val(),
        TTDNo4: $("txtTTDNo4").val(),                   
        CaliExpDate1: $("txtCaliExpDate1").val(),
        CaliExpDate2: $("txtCaliExpDate2").val(),
        CaliExpDate3: $("txtCaliExpDate3").val(),
        CaliExpDate4: $("txtCaliExpDate4").val()
    },
    success: function() {
        alert("Data added successfully");
    },
    failure: function() {
        alert("Please try again...");
    }
});
```

Comment: @JaromandaX :D yeah, your are riht

Comment: Still needs a comma between `success` and `failure` function.

Comment: thanks shayanypn.. :)..

Comment: @SumnerEvans yeah, thanks, i just update it

Answer (score 0):

Each `key-value` pair in an object is separated via a `,`. And assignment is via `:` between key and object.
Hence it should be:

```
data: {
  TTDNo1: $("txtTTDNo1").val(),
  TTDNo2: $("txtTTDNo2").val(),
  TTDNo3: $("txtTTDNo3").val(),
  // Etc
}
```